# haskell pattern maching - many conditions matching with one expression

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I wanna match many conditions with one expression in Haskell pattern matching.

for example,

```
data Message = HELLO | HI | GOODBYE | BYE

greeting x = case x of
  HELLO or HI          -> "hello"
  GOODBYE or BYE   -> "bye"
```

But I can't find how to do this.

sorry for my poor english.
thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try guards.  Ex,

```
data Message = HELLO | HI | GOODBYE | BYE deriving (Eq)

greeting x
    | x == HELLO   || x == HI   = "hello"
    | x == GOODBYE || x == BYE  = "bye"
```

Note you'll have to derive an `Eq` instance for your data type.  Check out the relevant section of [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions).

Comment: or `| elem x [HELLO,HI] = "hello"`